# How to do a running median of length 5

Tags: r

How can I calculate a running median of length 5?  I tried the `smooth` function but it only does running median of length 3.

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
library(zoo)
x <- 1:100
rollmedian(x,5)
```

Comment: @rinni i think it is a running average and not median

Answer (score 1):

In base R from `stats` package for those who does not want to install additional packages :

```
runmed(1:100, 5)
```

The parameter `endrule` allows to control strategy for the beginning and the end values.

```
runmed(1:10, 5, endrule = "keep")
> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

runmed(1:10, 5, endrule = "constant")
> [1] 3 3 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 8

runmed(1:10, 5, endrule = "median")
> [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: This gives me same as `1:100`, see here: `all(runmed(1:100, 5) == 1:100)` gives me a `TRUE`

Comment: I am not sure what the `endrule` parameter is. If it is necessary to answer the question, you should add it to the answer. Because now your answer simply produces a vector from 1 to 100 which does not answer the question

Comment: That is very kind! Honestly, I still do not understand how to make `runmed` running. I tried the three possible `endrules` but it did not give the expected output. Also, notice that you "switched" function, now you use `rollmedian` (as in the answer from vinux) and you should mention the library.